# Taylor's Theorem for functions of one variable

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider the function $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$

In the textbook it is given that the Taylor's series of the function is valid for $|x|<1$ and $x=1$. $\ln(1+x) = x - (x^2)/2 + ( x^3)/3 +......
$
The nth term of the series is $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} x^n$

The nth term converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ if $x$ belongs to $[-0.5,1]$

But for $x$ belongs to $(-1,-0.5)$ the nth term doesn't converge to $0$, which contradicts the statement of the text book. Can someone say me where am I wrong??

Comment: "But for x belongs to (-1,-0.5) the nth term doesn't converge to 0": what makes you say that ?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math Thank you.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Actually I am wrong about the nth term. Sorry! The nth term of the series is ((-1)^n-1)* ((x/1+c) ^n)/n . for the nth term to converge to 0, (x/ 1+c)^n has to be bounded, as 1/n converges to 0. Here c is a number that belongs to [0, x] from the statement of maclaurins series. When 0<x<1, (x/1+c) <1 and so is (x/ 1+c )^n. Similarly for 0>x>-0.5, |(x/1+c)| <1 but (x/1+c)^n  becomes unbounded for x<-0.5. Did you get my point???

Comment: @GanishAnanth: no, there is no $c$ in the series.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Although there is no c in the series, The condition for convergence of Taylor's series includes c. Check the link. https://youtu.be/-xvTzwot9MI

Comment: @GanishAnanth: add the relevant formulas to your post. Currently, we have to "guess" what you did.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you get the most bang for your buck with these problems by doing the Ratio Test. This is a generalization of the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n$, which converges if and only if $|r|<1$. (We'll actually make use of its closed-form later).

We must compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{n}}{n}}\right|
$$
$$
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|-x \cdot \frac{n}{n+1}\right|=|x|
$$This means as long as $|x|<1$- note this implies the region $(-1,-0.5)$ that you mentioned- the series will converge. Convergence at the boundary is delicate and must be checked case-by-case. At $x=1$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n},
$$which converges by the Alternating Series Test. At $x=-1$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n},
$$which is the divergent harmonic series. So the series converges for $x\in (-1,1]$.

Lastly, here's a quick sketch why the series equals $\ln(1+x)$ in this region. For $|r|<1$, the geometric series yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}
$$If we put $r=-x$ we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n = \frac{1}{1+x}
$$And now if we integrate both sides with respect to $x$ (legal for $x\in (-1,1)$) we have
$$
\int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n  \,dx = \ln(1+x) +C
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \int x^n  \,dx = \ln(1+x) +C
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}x^{n+1}= \ln(1+x) +C
$$A quick reindex and evaluating at $x=0$ to deduce $C=0$ gives the result:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}x^{n}= \ln(1+x) 
$$

Comment: Actually I am wrong about the nth term. Sorry! The nth term of the series is ((-1)^n-1)* ((x/1+c) ^n)/n . for the nth term to converge to 0, (x/ 1+c)^n has to be bounded, as 1/n converges to 0. Here c is a number that belongs to [0, x] from the statement of maclaurins series. When 0<x<1, (x/1+c) <1 and so is (x/ 1+c )^n. Similarly for 0>x>-0.5, |(x/1+c)| <1 but (x/1+c)^n  becomes unbounded for x<-0.5. Did you get my point???

Answer (score 1):

By the ratio test, the series converges when as of some $n$,

$$\left|\frac{\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\dfrac{x^n}n}\right|=\frac{n}{n+1}|x|<r<1$$ and this can be make true whenever $$|x|<1.$$